# Timestamp columns missing with postgres

Tags: postgresql, go, timestamp

I have a Postgres table called `certs` with 4 columns.

```
enter code here
\d certs
                        Table "public.certs"
Column       |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default
-------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
uuid         | character varying(255)      |           | not null |
serialnumber | bigint                      |           |          |
validtill    | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
validfrom    | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
Indexes:
"certs_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (uuid)
```

As you can see the last 2 columns are of type `timestamp`. Now I try to read all the rows in the columns in the following way

```
res, err := sql.DB.Query("SELECT * from certs;")
if err == nil{
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(res.Columns())
defer res.Close()
var id string
var serialNumber int64
var validFrom time.Time
var validTill time.Time
fmt.Println(res.ColumnTypes())
for res.Next() {
    err := res.Scan(&id, &serialNumber, &validFrom, &validTill)
    fmt.Println(res.Columns())
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("error %v", err)
    } else {
        cs.Certs[id] = serialNumber
    }
```

Basically I am trying to decode values retrieved.

I get the following error

```
 error sql: expected 2 destination arguments in Scan, not 4
```

Also the print `res.columns()` prints this

```
[uuid serialnumber] <nil>
```

As you can see there is error and also the `columns` printed don't show `validtill` and `validfrom`. Independent checking of database using `psql` does indeed verifies that there are `validtill` and `validfrom` columns with data in them.

What am I missing here? Why the error?

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the same database in both your Go program an psql? Did you change the search_path in the Go program so it's querying the certs table in a different schema? Do you have permission to read the columns? What happens if you mention them explicitly (`SELECT uuid, ...` instead of `SELECT *`)?

Comment: It really looks like your table is missing those columns. I concur with Peter: Ensure that the database you're connecting to actually has those columns on that table.

Comment: @Peter, not possible. I verified them. I made a small change in the same codebase to delete the table and the table was deleted when checked through `psql` . If the go app connected to some other database then one connected with psql, the cert table would not have been dropped.

Comment: Can you get what you want by plain sql query? Can you change Select stirng from * to uuid, serialnumber, validtill, validfrom?

Answer (score -2):

There is a specific way of working with nullable fields in Go. You should use nullable types like `sql.NullString` or `sql.NullInt64`, etc. Otherwise you will get Scan errors.

Also you should define vars for Scan inside `res.Next` block.

This article explains in details how to use it - https://pliutau.com/working-with-db-nulls/

Comment: This does not relate to the question. Null fields will still show up in the result--as `nil`.

Comment: Maybe, but that doesn't make this an answer to the question.

Comment: @AlexPliutau, I changed the schema to so that columns are no longer nullable but the issue persists.

Comment: @amrx: To be clear, there is no reason to change the schema to be non-nullable. This is completely unrelated to your situation.

Comment: @amrx you should also define local variables for scan (var ...) inside `res.Next` block.